# authorize api keys in django

Tags: python, html, django, api

How to verify the api keys in django? im using rapidapi and they have this key and how do i authorize it with the url

views.py

```
def thanks(request):
    url = "https://webknox-trivia-knowledge-facts-v1.p.rapidapi.com/trivia/random"
    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "webknox-trivia-knowledge-facts-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_data = json.loads(r.text)
    print(json_data)
    return render(request,'portofolio/thankyou.html',headers)
```

The print returns "{'message': 'Missing RapidAPI application key. Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys to learn how to get your API application key.'}"
I have a key and how do I authorize it? and use it in my django template! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send headers to rapidapi:

```
def thanks(request):
    url = "https://webknox-trivia-knowledge-facts-v1.p.rapidapi.com/trivia/random"
    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "webknox-trivia-knowledge-facts-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) # here you need to send headers
    json_data = json.loads(r.text)
    print(json_data)
    return render(request,'portofolio/thankyou.html')
```

Comment: then wt do i use in my template?

Comment: well, can you describe better the flow of what you're trying to perform?

Comment: display the output of this in my template? nvm i got it thanks for the idea